# mkdir() create two directories when called once, why is this strange behavior?

Tags: php, mkdir, tmp

If I put the following code in a `.php` file and run it in my browser, *two* directories are created in my `/tmp` directory, each with a `uniqid()` based name:

```
<?php

$tmpfolder = uniqid("test_");
echo $tmpfolder;
mkdir("/tmp/" . $tmpfolder);
exit();
```

It's exactly as if I had run the code twice. One name is displayed from the `echo`, but another one is created as well.

Has anyone seen this strange behavior before? I have no idea on how to solve it, and thought someone here would.

Comment: And you’re sure your browser does only send one request?

Comment: Have tried a couple of different browsers? Do you get the same result?Any addons in  your browser that might execute it twice?

Comment: but what is relation with php and browser ? php is server side scripting language

Comment: It looks like one request in the Chrome web inspector, but in fact the problem does not occur when running the page in Firefox or when fetching it using curl. This is odd.